# Parse Error: Unexpected double quotes in array

Tags: php, arrays, string

I have an array structure similar to below:

```
$system_data = array(
    87 => array(
        'message' => "{$message_name} logged a new activity.",
        'description' => 'patient logged a new activity',
        'message_type' => 3
    )
)
```

When a function is called, it finds the referred message string (from the ID - 87) and injects the related `$message_name` variable value into the string. It works if I return a static double quoted string that directly injects the variable, but when I transposed this to my array (changing for double quotes on the string and adding the `{$variable_name}` syntax to it, I get the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'

Taking the `{$}` out of my string solves the problem, so that must mean that the double quotes aren't throwing an error with the array, but that it's the `{$}` throwing an error with the double quotes. Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

As requested, here's how the code is set:

```
class Log_model extends CI_Model {
   const SUPERVISOR_PROGRAM_UPDATED = 87;

    private $system_data = array(
        87 => array(
            'message' => "{$message_name} logged a new activity.",
            'description' => 'patient logged a new activity',
            'message_type' => 3
        )
    )

    /*functions here*/
}
```

Comment: at what line are you receiving this error? Also, I cannot [reproduce the error](http://ideone.com/OO5i52).

Comment: No parse error here http://codepad.org/sdyzGNts. Parse errors happen before your program begins running so you can throw all your "how it gets to this point in the code" scenarios out the window.

Comment: @Jefffrey 'message' => ..., as stated above.

Comment: @MikeB Could this be a PHP versioning issue?

Comment: Can we see what you have before that declaration?

Comment: @Prusprus No. http://3v4l.org/Kq9Qg. Show your full code.

Comment: Any chance that you left a "-delimited string open somewhere before this code?

Comment: The fact that I can remove the {$} from the string from above and the code will work fine, tells me that I should still get a parse error if it were an open double quote somewhere. Or is this a wrong assumption? I'll dumb the code down to see if this has any improvements.

Comment: There you go - you can't use dynamic elements when setting properties in a class. properties must be all static. Example 1 http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php "This declaration may include an initialization, but this initialization must be a constant value"

Comment: Ok, thanks. Never thought of thinking at the error's context. So because it needs to have a constant value that it can associate when compiling, that means I can't push a value by reference either? Since I'm trying to system messages with dynamic data, having to recompile an array every time my function is called can be heavy, am I best just using a PHP search and replace method that finds my custom delimiter for a variable name and replaces it with a variable, thus avoiding this static mess? - All this because I'm trying to keep everything (such as variable injection) as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With MikeB and Zgr024's hints, this is what I've come to (not the best solution, but something that works and keeps the flexibility and dynamicness i need for my script):

```
class Log_model extends CI_Model {
    const SUPERVISOR_PROGRAM_UPDATED = 87;

    private static $system_data = array(
        87 => array(
            'message' => "{$message_name} logged a new activity.",
            'description' => 'patient logged a new activity',
            'message_type' => 3
        )
    )

    /*data is a set of values (key->value) to be injected into the string (included and retrieved depending on the log_type_id needed when calling this function)*/
    public function generate_message($log_type_id = FALSE, $data = array()){
    $message = self::$system_data [$log_type_id]['message'];
    foreach($data as $key=>$value){
    $message = str_replace("{%".$key."%}", $value, $message, $i);
    }

    return $message;
}
```

}

Comment: I was going to suggest injecting the variables or the entire array as a parameter under the changeMessage function I previously wrote, but it seems you've already figure that out.

Answer (score 1):

```
class Log_model extends CI_Model {
   const SUPERVISOR_PROGRAM_UPDATED = 87;

    private $system_data = array(
        87 => array(
            'description' => 'patient logged a new activity',
            'message_type' => 3
        )
    )

   private function changeMessage ($message_name) { 
        $system_data[87]['message'] = "{$message_name} logged a new activity.";
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 in that I understand that I can reinstantiate the strings when I have the correct variables declared (later in my script, post-compilation), but given that my variables injected into my strings may be different, depending on the message, I can't afford to have any static execution. My first thought was to replace your changeMessage by a refresh() function, which pushes an array of variables thru each message, but the same message might be used for two difference instances (with two different names), so I need to maintain a template of messages. I'll add my solution, tell me what you think.