# Unexpected Double Quote in Array definition

Tags: php

I am seeing a parse error in the definition of an array as a private, static member of a class.

The code in question is:

```
// %1$s for table name
// %2$s for character set collate
// Version 1 is the initial DB layout
private static $version_sql = array(
    1   =>  "CREATE TABLE %1$s (
                id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                chance_id int(11) UNSIGNED,
                user_fingerprint varchar(32),
                state tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                expires int(11) UNSIGNED,
                email varchar(255),
                PRIMARY KEY  id (id)
                UNIQUE KEY chance_user (chance_id,user_fingerprint)
            ) %2$s;"
);
```

The parse error raised is `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '"'`, and the line number given is that of the first line of the SQL definition (the one with `CREATE TABLE` on it).

I've read [Parse Error: Unexpected double quotes in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20889702/parse-error-unexpected-double-quotes-in-array) which is a similar error but seems to be more to do with the use of string interpolation in a context where the referenced variable is not available, which is not something I am doing here.

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to escape your `$` chars since you're using double-quotes, PHP tries to replace `$s` with the content of the variable of the same name, which is illegal for `statics`.

Comment: what version of PHP are you using? I would expect to see an error `PHP Fatal error:  Constant expression contains invalid operations` because you can't use variables in a variable declaration in PHP 7.

Comment: OOk, I haven't come across that before, is that just using `\ `, like `"CREATE TABLE %1\$s` ?

Comment: Either that, or just use single-quotes for the whole thing.

Comment: @JeffPuckettII 5.5.9 - I wasn't intending to use variables but based on what @ccKep has said I might be doing so unintentionally. The $ signs are there as the string is a template to later be passed through `sprintf`

Comment: Thanks for the quick help - if you want to throw your comment into an answer I'd happily checkmark you

Comment: Regarding your last comment: It sounds like you're using sprintf to build your query (hence you'd be required to sanitize your placeholders yourself). Might I suggest using prepared statements and placeholders instead?

Comment: unfortunately not an option in this case, it's a Wordpress plugin and the table creation DDL is to be passed to Wordpress' `dbDelta()` function. Rest assured, all other queries in the plugin are using prepared statements through `$wpdb->prepare()`, but to get db updates and DDL working the framework heavily favours using dbDelta (or doing a lot of wheel reinventing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape your `$` chars since your string  contains `$s` in double-quotes. PHP tries to fill in the contents of that variable (which is not allowed in `static` context).

Either replace your `$` with `\$` or use single-quotes for the whole string.

```
// %1$s for table name
// %2$s for character set collate
// Version 1 is the initial DB layout
private static $version_sql = array(
    1   =>  'CREATE TABLE %1$s (
                id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                chance_id int(11) UNSIGNED,
                user_fingerprint varchar(32),
                state tinyint UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
                expires int(11) UNSIGNED,
                email varchar(255),
                PRIMARY KEY  id (id)
                UNIQUE KEY chance_user (chance_id,user_fingerprint)
            ) %2$s;'
);
```